# UIElement equivalent of [self.scene nodeAtPoint:touchLoc];

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking to find out which UI element is in the location of a user's tap. Up to now I haven't been able to find anything that acts like The SK method :

```
[self.scene nodeAtPoint:touchLoc];
```

Basically I want the same functionality of this function, but for UIElements.
P.S my elements are all on top of a UIScrollView, not sure if that makes a difference
Thanks in advance!